# Add space between HTML elements such as H4 only using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<h4>FOLLOW US</h4>
<h4>CONTACT US</h4>
<h4>PAYMENT METHODS</h4>
```

Hello everyone, I need to put all these three elements in a row and make space between them, I don't want to use any additional HTML markup for example:add classes to every element. I want to use only CSS.

From similar question I tried to use such thing but this is what it led to:

```
footer>h4{
    grid-area: firstfooter;
    padding: 48% 0% 0% 0%;
}

h4 ~ h4{
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

[image]

But I need this like this:
[image]

If I change margin or padding it doesn't effect on result at all.

Comment: why not change the padding or margin?

Comment: Can't you just add the padding like so? `padding-top: 48%`. Also, please research before asking on Stack Overflow. Google is a very useful tool, and people should learn to use it :)

Comment: If I change padding or margin it doesn't affect the result

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<br>` HTML tag or add `margin` in CSS like this:

```
h4 {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Same thing was happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box! This only works if the h4 elements are in a footer

```
footer{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

You can also say space-around instead of space-between. This will add space on the left of the first h4 and on the right of the last h4.

Comment: there is a difference between space around and space between, by the way

Comment: Argh, faster than me :p

Comment: corn on the cob. Thanks for pointing that out. My wording could have been interpreted like that. I have changed it to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I don't want use flex,only grid, but thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

## This should work:

```css
    footer{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content: space-between; 
    }
    footer h4{
       position: relative;
       display: inline;
       font-family: sans-serif;
     }
```

```html
<footer>
  <h4>I FORGOT</h4>
  <h4>WHAT THE </h4>
  <h4>WORDS WERE</h4>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
   footer h4 {
        margin-right: 30%;
   }
```

Or

```
footer h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Same thing was happen

Comment: Is the container wide enough? Is there enough space to distance the elements?

Comment: Try
footer h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}